# Subtyping with function pointers, structs, unions, and enums

Tags: c, struct, enums, unions, subtyping

**Preface:** Yes, this is homework. I've been working on it for the last week or so and Googling has not helped. I'm not looking for someone to complete my homework for me, I'm more concerned about understanding the material and am just looking for any constructive criticism or nudges in the right direction.

I have 3 shape structs (circle, triangle, and rectangle), a union of the 3 shape structs, a struct of function pointers, an enum of shapes, and a struct of all of the above (the union, shape type, and function pointers).

**Question:** I need to complete the subtyping/supertyping to allow the driver to operate on Shapes without knowing their details. I believe I have most of the framework complete but am a bit lost on the function pointers and using the ShapeType enum and Shape struct to implement them.

**prototypes.h**

```
#include <my_struct.h>

void InitializeCircle(struct Shape *, double radius, double origin, double originY);
void InitializeRectangle(struct Shape *, double minX, double maxX, double minY, double maxY);
void InitializeTriangle(struct Shape *, Triangle *, double pt1X, double pt2X, double minY, double maxY);

double GetCircleArea(struct Shape *);
double GetCircleArea(struct Shape *);
double GetTriangleArea(struct Shape *);

void GetCircleBoundingBox(struct Shape *, double *);
void GetRectangleBoundingBox(struct Shape *, double *);
void GetTriangleBoundingBox(struct Shape *, double *);
```

**my_struct.h**

```
// DEFINITIONS FOR THE THREE SHAPES:
typedef struct {
    double radius, origin, originY, area;
} Circle;

typedef struct {
    double pt1X, pt2X, minY, maxY, area;
} Triangle;

typedef struct {
    double minX, maxX, minY, maxY, area;
} Rectangle;


// SUBTYPING/SUPERTYPING:
struct Shape;   // Defined later

typedef struct {
    // Pointers to functions -> two data members: GetArea & GetBoundingBox
    double (*GetArea)(struct Shape *);
    GetArea = // NEED TO IMPLEMENT

    double (*GetBoundingBox)(struct Shape *, double *bbox);
    GetBoudingBox = // NEED TO IMPLEMENT

} FunctionTable;

typedef union {
    // Shape structs:
    Circle c;
    Triangle t;
    Rectangle r;
} ShapeUnion;

typedef enum {
    // Identifies the 3 types
    Circle,
    Rectangle,
    Triangle
} ShapeType;

typedef struct {
    ShapeUnion su;
    ShapeType st;
    FunctionTable ft;
} Shape;
```

**my_struct.c**

```
/* This file should contain the 9 functions defined in prototypes.h */

#include <prototypes.h>

// Initialize Structs
void InitializeCircle(struct Shape *c, double r, double o, double oY) {
    c->radius = r;
    c->origin = o;
    c->originY = oY;
}
void InitializeRectangle(struct Shape *r, double miX, double maX, double miY, double maY) {
    r->minX = miX;
    r->maxX = maX;
    r->minY = miY;
    r->maxY = maY;
}
void InitializeTriangle(struct Shape *t, double p1X, double p2X, double miY, double maY) {
    t->pt1X = p1X;
    t->pt2X = p2X;
    t->minY = miY;
    t->maxY = maY;
}

// Get Area
double GetCircleArea(struct Shape *c) {
    c->area = 3.14159*c->radius*c->radius;
    return c->area;
}
double GetRectangleArea(struct Shape *r) {
    r->area = ((r->maxX-r->minX)*(r->maxY-r->minY));
    return r->area;
}
double GetTriangleArea(struct Shape *t) {
    t->area = (((t->pt2X-t->pt1X)*(t->maxY-t->minY))/2);
    return t->area;
}

// Get Bounding Box
void GetCircleBoundingBox(struct Shape *c, double *bbox) {
    bbox[0] = c->origin-c->radius;  // lower left corner
    bbox[1] = c->origin+c->radius;  // lower right corner
    bbox[2] = c->originY-c->radius; // upper left corner
    bbox[3] = c->originY+c->radius; // upper right corner
}
void GetRectangleBoundingBox(struct Shape *r, double *bbox) {
    bbox[0] = r->minX;
    bbox[1] = r->maxX;
    bbox[2] = r->minY;
    bbox[3] = r->maxY;
}
void GetTriangleBoundingBox(struct Shape *t, double *bbox) {
    bbox[0] = t->pt1X;  // minX
    bbox[1] = t->pt2X;  // maxX
    bbox[2] = 0;        // minY
    bbox[3] = t->maxY;  // maxY
}
```

**driver.c**

```
#include <prototypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct Shape shapes[9];
    int i;

    InitializeCircle(shapes+0, 1, 0, 0);
    InitializeCircle(shapes+1, 1.5, 6, 8);
    InitializeCircle(shapes+2, 0.5, -3, 4);

    InitializeRectangle(shapes+3, 0, 1, 0, 1);
    InitializeRectangle(shapes+4, 1, 1.1, 10, 20);
    InitializeRectangle(shapes+5, 1.5, 3.5, 10, 12);

    InitializeTriangle(shapes+6, 0, 1, 0, 1);
    InitializeTriangle(shapes+7, 0, 1, 0, 0.1);
    InitializeTriangle(shapes+8, 0, 10, 0, 50);

    for (i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)
    {
        double bbox[4];
        printf("Shape %d\n", i);
        printf("\tArea: %f\n", shapes[i].ft.GetArea(shapes+i));
        shapes[i].ft.GetBoundingBox(shapes+i, bbox);
        printf("\tBbox: %f-%f, %f-%f\n", bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3]);
    }
}
```

Any insight would/will be greatly appreciated. Again, I'm not looking for anyone to do my homework for me, I'm just hoping to get past this roadblock.

Comment: Can't you just setup the function table with the relevant function pointers in InitializeXYZ?

Comment: @AlanAu Thanks for your input! I believe I could, but this assignment if focused around implementing function pointers "GetArea" and "GetBoundingBox" in my FunctionTable struct. Unfortunately, there's no way around that.

Comment: But you can't put code body directly into struct definitions. So you have to have the functions implemented elsewhere. And then in the Initialize functions you fill in the FunctionTable struct members with pointers to the actual functions that were implemented. Unless I'm totally misunderstanding your requirements.

Comment: Note that `struct Shape;` and `typedef struct {...} Shape;` are not the same type. Latter needs to be `typedef struct Shape {...} Shape;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define function table for each type:

```
// This is global, and used for all circle types. 
// Could be declared 'static' if table and init functions are in the same file.
FunctionTable const CircleFuncs = {
    GetCircleArea,
    GetCircleBoundingBox
};
```

Since table can be shared for all shapes of the same type, we only need pointer for it:

```
typedef struct Shape { // <- note the fixed type name also
    ShapeUnion su;
    ShapeType st;
    FunctionTable const * ft;
} Shape;
```

Initialization function should assign the table to shape:

```
void InitializeCircle(struct Shape *c, double r, double o, double oY) {
    /* other inits here*/
    c->ft = &CircleFuncs;
}
```